# cypress - use of a function loses parameter data

Tags: javascript, function, cypress

I'm using Cypress and, in order to be able to use a request from several files, I want to set it in a function. This request is a login request.
At the beginning I have a file xx.js that holds this request, and I want to put it a function called "login", in another file that will contain all 'system' functions (called system.js) and then call it through the function.

In my xx.js file, the code is like this

```
    console.log(user)
    cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'system/http/login', // baseUrl is prepended to url
    form: true, // indicates the body should be form urlencoded and sets Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded headers
    body: {
      u: user.username,
      p: user.password,
      referer: '/rootapp/index.html'
    },
    failOnStatusCode: true
  })
```

When executed, the log shows

```
user :  {username: "myName", password: "myPwd"}
password: "myPwd"
username: "myName"
__proto__: Object
```

I chose to create a function in my system.js, I import it in my xx.js file and I call it in place of the request, passing user as a parameter

```
exports.login = function (user) {
    console.log("parameter user : ", user)
    if (user =! undefined)
    {
        console.log("u : ", user.username)
        console.log("p : ", user.password)
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'system/http/login', // baseUrl is prepended to url
            form: true, // indicates the body should be form urlencoded and sets Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded headers
            body: {
            u: user.username,
            p: user.password,
            referer: '/rootapp/index.html'
            },
            failOnStatusCode: true
        })
    }
    else
        throw(new Error("no user identified"));
  };
```

But my request returns 403, when I look at the console log, it shows

```
parameter user :  {username: "myName", password: "myPwd"}
password: "myPwd"
username: "myName"
__proto__: Object
u :  undefined
p :  undefined
```

How is it possible that I lose data, is it a question of type of parameter ? I'm a beginner in cypress and javascript

thanks for any clue of what's happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the line `if (user =! undefined)` a typo?

Normally that would be

```
if (user !== undefined) {
```

or even just this would work

```
if (user) {
```

Comment: it works now, the thing that I don't understand is why it ended up with this kind of error ? I thought it would raise an error on the typo

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to figure it out too. Best guess, that `=! undefined` first assigns the opposite of undefined (whatever that is) to `user` then the same value is tested by the `if()`.